# How to paste text into Vim Visual Mode?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

i am working in vim and I would like to paste yanked text into Visual Mode. Is it possible?

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cut/copy_and_paste_using_visual_selection use this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `p` command works in visual mode, too (cp. `:help v_p`). However, the default register contents will be overwritten. (My [ReplaceWithRegister plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703) has an alternative command that keeps it.)

Alternatively, you can `s` or `c` to replace the visual selection, and then use one of the insert mode commands like `<C-R>{register}` to insert the register contents. For pasting the default register, you need to use `"_s` to avoid overwriting its contents.